# get updated state in function after dispatch React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux

I have an Input like this below and firstly when I click on it I need to change a state of filters in Redux memory. After that I want to read that changed state inside onFilterClick function and fetch filtered items by backend API. How can I do this so: after changing the states in the redux, the current state in onFilterClick is read?

I tried to do `dispatch(changeState(...)).then(() => onFilterClick(...))` but it still doesn't see the current state.

```
const { currentFilters } = useSelector((state) => state.filtersSlice);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
let history = useHistory();

<StyledInput
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={() => {
            dispatch(
              changeState({
                filterType: filterType.name,
                id: text,
                input: filterType.input,
              })
            );
            onFilterClick(
              currentFilters,
              dispatch,
              history
            );
          }}
          checked={checked.includes(text)}
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current issue that you have is that `currentFilters` is not up to date after the dispatch because it keep the previous reference,
You have multiple possibilities to fix this:

### Using a thunk

```js
export const stuff = (filterType, text, history): AppThunk => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // Step 1 you dispatch
  dispatch(
    changeState({
      filterType: filterType.name,
      id: text,
      input: filterType.input,
    })
  );
  // Step 2 you call a selector with a fresh state
  const currentFilters = currentFiltersSelector(getState())
  // Step 3 you call `onFilterClick` (this can be a thunk on it's own as it use dispatch)
  onFilterClick(
    currentFilters,
    dispatch,
    history
  );
}
```

### Using hooks

```js
const { currentFilters } = useSelector((state) => state.filtersSlice);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
let history = useHistory();

const onFilterClikCallback = useCallback((filters) => {
  onFilterClick(
    filters,
    dispatch,
    history
  );
}, [history]);

useEffect(() => {
  // When filters change call onFilterClikCallback
  onFilterClikCallback(currentFilters)
}, [currentFilters])

<StyledInput
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={() => {
            dispatch(
              changeState({
                filterType: filterType.name,
                id: text,
                input: filterType.input,
              })
            );
          }}
          checked={checked.includes(text)}
/>
```

Note: I do not know what onFilterClick do in your app but this can be a thunk on it's own

Note: The first approach might be better as you'll do this logic outside of react and you not rely on state update to trigger it.

Comment: Thank You! The first option made my day;)